# Orthogonal Vector application

Tags: orthogonality

Is there any real life example or application of orthogonal vector where 3 vector A,B and C, A is orthogonal to both B and C but B and C are not orthogonal to each other?

Comment: Suppose you are applying force to a lever arm.  The force is not perpendicular to the lever arm (say you have cable attached to the arm,  The direction of force is constant but the lever is moving.)  Torque is perpendicular to the force vector and lever arm, but the direction of force is not perpendicular to the lever arm.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

[image]

This is a Switzerland  ''real life'' example (do you see the three vectors?).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: The log side is a vector orthogonal to any couple of sides of the triangular basis of this triangular prism.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, imagine A B and C describing moving objects, where A is a moving object, being shot from B towards C.
Or just think of an object being pushed by forces A, B and C. It is kind of a vague question, so i think there would be plenty of cases where you could describe the situation like this.